# Excel ROW Matching

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, formula

So guys the FIFA world cup is on.. me and a group of my friends have voted on teams who think might win on an excel spreadsheet. I want to find a way where we can tally the vote and on the last cell it'll tell us how many people voted for a particular team on each match.

[image: Img]

For example on the side of each rows it'll say the most voted and the percentage of the vote. In our example it's Brazil and 80% of my friends think they will win and so on..
I know there is a excel formula for MATCH but the compares columns is there way to use this for ROW comparison along with the percentage

Comment: Did you consider using `COUNTIF` (which counts the number of times something appears in a range)?

Comment: A simple `COUNTIF` should do the trick, assuming that I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula should work to give you the team with the highest votes that you can drag down your list.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))>=COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999)),MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)&" - "&TEXT((COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))/COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<>"&"")),"0.00%"),MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999)&" - "&TEXT((COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999))/COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<>"&"")),"0.00%"))
```

Using a `MID` function with a `FIND` function you can find that name of each team. To find the first team you can use

```
=MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)
```

To find the second team you can use

```
=MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999)
```

You can then use this formulas as your criteria for your `COUNTIF`

So instead of having

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"Brazil")
```

where you have to type every team in manually you can insert the `MID`

```
=COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))
```

And repeat for the second team using the other `MID` formula

This will give you the `COUNTIF` for the two team Vs each other.

Wrap this into an `IF` statement where if count of team1 is greater than count of team2, show team1 and team1 votes / total votes as percentage with a `TEXT`.

```
'Where if

=IF(COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))>=COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999))`

'Then

MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1)&" - "&TEXT((COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,1,FIND(" ",A2,1)-1))/COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<>"&"")),"0.00%")`

'Else

MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999)&" - "&TEXT((COUNTIF($B2:$G2,MID(A2,FIND("Vs ",A2,1)+3,999))/COUNTIF($B2:$G2,"<>"&"")),"0.00%")`
```